# What is causing the high latency during method call within same network?

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, profiling, latency

I am running a Spring boot Java Service backed by Postgres.

When examining some high latency calls and debugging with more logs, I discovered that most of the latency attributes to the call from controller to DAO method. This doesn't include any transformation or DB call. Just java method call from Controller to the entry point in DAO method.

How did I conclude?

- Added print statements in Controller right before calling DAO (say t1)
- Added print statement in the first line of called DAO (say t2)
- In all the high latency calls the t2-t1 contributes to ~80% of the overall request latency.

```
class MyController {
  @Autowired 
  MyDAO mydao;

  public void serviceAPI() {
     // Do something...

     logger.info("Right before DAO call");  // time t1
     myDAO.someDAOfunctionality();

     // Do something...
  }

}

class MyDAO {
  public void someDAOfunctionality() {
     logger.info("First line of DAO call");  // time t2

     // Do something..
  }
```

**PS:** I tried profiling the requests using a local instance of the server. That has been inconclusive so far.
So wondering what could be causing the delay when a lightweight call is made within the same network.

Comment: What is the number of requests you are making on the endpoint while profiling locally?